# ParseExact and TryParseExact not working as expected

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, .net-4.0

I am trying to convert several different times of time, tried with `DateTime.ParseExact` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` and both didn't worked for me.

The data I have to parse is in the following formats:

```
5 PM
1:00
1:00 AM
12:00
18:00
```

I've tried the following:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(stDate, "H:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out visStartHour);

visStartHour = DateTime.ParseExact(stDate, "H:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I have also tried to use a string array of formats and none works:

```
string[] timeFormats = new string[] { "H tt", "H:mm tt", "HH:mm", "H:mm" };
```

Also tried using:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `TryParse()`

```
DateTime result;

DateTime.TryParse("5 PM", out result);
DateTime.TryParse("1:00", out result);
DateTime.TryParse("1:00 AM", out result);
DateTime.TryParse("12:00", out result);
DateTime.TryParse("18:00", out result);
```

etc...